# Converting html pages to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to convert my normal HTML website which consists of home, about, and T&C pages to WordPress, I have created the theme folder which Consists of index.php, functions.php, header.php, and footer.php files. So now my question is how can I add and link my other pages (about, T&C pages).

Comment: is your question: "How to display menu items?"

Comment: yes, how to create those pages and link them in navbar

Answer (score 0):

You have to use /* **Template Name: Home** */ on your custom page.
For more example:
[see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a menu see code below and link to Codex

```
 function mytheme_register_nav_menu(){
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary_menu' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'text_domain' ),
        'footer_menu'  => __( 'Footer Menu', 'text_domain' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_register_nav_menu', 0 );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/